# Custom Emoji's package in Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, emoji

I want to build a plugin with custom Emoji pack, so when a user will download and install it he could use my custom Emoji.
My Emoji will be very different from the known Emoji and I do realize
that user without my plugin won't be able to see my custom Emoji's.

I tried to use the most popular Emoji's app in Google play like:
Kika Emoji Keyboard

But the experience is very bad, the emoji just look different on the keyboard but when I used them in an app like whatsapp they look the same as the built in ones..

So, my question is:
How can i build a custom plugin with my custom Emoji pack so when a user will install it he could use my Emoji's together with the regular Emoji's?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your custom emojis within your app but you can't use those in other apps as custom unicodes are not supported by android unless you use within your app.For instance most of the emojis supported by Skype are not supported by another apps.